# in the discussion & at the discussion

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to understand the difference between **in the discussion** and **at the discussion**. Could you help please based on my own sentences?

> In the discussion the participants considered the issues related to competitiveness and socio-economic divisions in the European Union.

and

> The participants at the discussion considered the issues related to competitiveness and socio-economic divisions in the European Union.

If I want to mention that someone participated in the discussion, should I use a phrase **X in (*or at*) the discussion** (only a phrase, not a whole sentence).

Comment: You can also say *participants of the discussion*.

Comment: I want to use _in_ or _at_.

Comment: I would say that both are correct, but with slightly different meanings: discussion as *conversation* (in the discussion), and discussion as *event* (at the discussion).

Answer (score 4):

**At the discussion:** We don't know if this person is actually talking, but he *is* in fact present

**In the discussion:** We know that this person is participating in the discussion

Answer (score 3):

This might just be me being very slightly picky, but

> Participants **in** the discussion

were actively involved in talking about it

> Participants **at** the discussion

were present but not necessarily taking part, merely watching on as others discussed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a very slight difference.
'at the discussion' refers to the 'event' ... 
People at the discussion had candy and chocolate.
This one points more towards the discussion as an event.

People, in the discussion, argued against 'something' ...
This might refer towards what was being discussed, the proceedings of the discussion.